# Javascript or jquery - is there a way to dismantle an anchor tag

Tags: jquery, html, href

so that it'll only respond to a right mouse click? If the user left clicks on the link I want to just hide it. I can capture right or left mouse clicks through:

```
$(".hideDataFileLink").live('mousedown', function(e) { 
    if (e.which == 3) { 
        $(this).slideUp('fast');
    } 
});
```

where 1 = left, 2 = middle, 3 = right. In the end, either click hides the link after the click but this is for downloading a text dump from a database and if you left click on the link you leave the page and load the text in your browser. I don't want that option to happen.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just add `return false` or `e.preventDefault()` to stop the browser following the link:

```
$(".hideDataFileLink").live('mousedown', function(e) { 
    e.preventDefault();
    if (e.which == 3) { 
        $(this).slideUp('fast');
    } 
    // or return false here, but that will also stop the event from
    // bubbling up to the parent which is needed in some cases
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Just include something like this in your function to return false if the user clicks the right mouse button, and leave the rest alone.

```
if (e.which == 1) { 
  return false;
}
```